# What is the syntax for Dsynchronize "exclude filter" for files 's full path to exclude bin\* and obj\* of a C# solution?

Tags: windows

Dsynchronize is a great free tool to sync two folders.

I'm using it to sync two solutions checked out from two different TFS Team Collection.

I want to exclude the following:

1. All files in `bin` folder
2. All files in `obj` folder

I tried `bin\*; obj\*` but it doesn't work.

How can I do that?

ps. Though, trying `*.g.*` and `*cache*` help to exclude the files whose names match with the filter. It seems the filter is applied to the file name only NOT the full path of the file

[image]

Comment: Please don't create new tags so often. Most of those are not really meaningful on their own (such as "exclude"—you cannot be an expert in excluding something). Also, check the spelling: it's Dsynchronize. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I used `*.git*` to ignore the git folder, you could try `*obj*`, though this may ignore any file with 'obj' in it's name